# How can I get sessions to work if I'm using Google App Engine + Django 1.1?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, session

Is there a way for me to get sessions working?  I know Django has built in session management, and GAE has some tools for it if you're using their watered down version of Django 0.96, but is there a way to get sessions to work if you're trying to use GAE w/ Django 1.1 (i.e. use_library() call).  I assume using a db-backed session doesn't work, and a file system backed one won't work b/c we don't have access to the filesystem if we deploy to the Google production servers.

This kinda worked (as in didn't crap out) when I used SessionMiddleware backed by a local-memory backed cache and a non-persistent cache (i.e. setting SESSION_ENGINE to django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache).  But the session never seems to persist in this case, no matter how I set the timeouts.  A new session key is generated on every page reload.  Maybe this is b/c the GAE assumes complete statelessness with each request and blows away my local cache?

Apologies in advance, I'm pretty new to Python.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the django sessions, you need to use the google django helper here: http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/

Which says:

> Support for the db and cache session backed modules when using Django 1.0 alpha

Even though it says 1.0 alpha, it means 1.0 and above.